# busco problemas donde no *los* hay

Tags: pronombres, objetos-directos, redundancia, haber

I have just heard a Shakira song which says:

> Yo busco problemas donde no los hay.

Is the pronoun "los" necessary in this sentence or is the redundancy used for emphasis? I'd just say "Busco problemas donde no hay".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pronoun *los* is optional in this case. It's not really redundant because the impersonal form of *haber* normally takes a direct object. The form without the pronoun is [elliptical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)): the pronoun is suppressed because it's clear from context what is being referred to.

Note that *hay* is third person singular regardless of the noun that accompanies it, precisely because it's an object and not a subject. Here lies the main difference between impersonal *haber* and its synonyms *estar, existir, ocurrir* (see [DPD, *haber*, 4](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=haber)). So you can say

> *Busco problemas donde no (los) hay.*

with or without the pronoun *los*, but you can only say

> *Busco problemas donde no existen.*

without any object pronoun.

Comment: As "existir" takes no indirect object, I assume that "no los existen" instead of "no los hay" would be wrong. Right?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista - I think you are correct about that.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista "haber" (as a main verb) is transitive, while "existir" is intransitive.

Comment: Así que vas por la vida diciendo ´¿"Busco problemas donde no hay"?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Yes, it's as you say. Indeed there's a note precisely about that [here](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=haber) (search for "estar, existir, ocurrir"). I'm adding it to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It may sound redundant –being optional, as the sentence would be still be understood without it– but having the pronoun (***los***) in place helps get the point across more effectively.

There are other similar cases where redundant object pronouns act beneficially, bringing a reinforced, straightforward reference.

> *Cuando encuentro buenos higos, **los** compro*

Though the object is already understood, it does not hurt to point to it repeatedly.

Also:

> *Habia excelentes manzanas, pero no [**las**] compré hoy*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101697/discussion-on-answer-by-user2325442-busco-problemas-donde-no-los-hay).